# Como chamar a aplicação de "ligar número" em uma webview?

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma parte no meu aplicativo que é uma webview, como fazer para que ao clicar no telefone da webview, abrir a intent de chamadas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa necessariamente chamar um `Intent`, você pode usar o ["tel URI scheme"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#tel:), desta maneira:

```
<a href="tel:0110000000">Chamar</a>
```

Ou com javascript:

```
window.location = "tel:0110000000";
```

Comment: vou da uma olhada, valeu

Comment: funcionou!valeu