# Permitir link de numero telefone em app android studio

Tags: android

E criei um app webview, e estou testando ele com pasta local e web, e no app tem o link html de ligar direto de um link com o numero de telefone, pois se trata de um site mobile, como permitir no app que isso funcione, ao clicar no chamar auxilio ele ja inicia a ligação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

achei a resposta depois de muito custo e adaptação

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebBrowser());

private class WebBrowser extends WebViewClient {


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Acho que não é necessário, até aonde me recordo basta ter `tel:` no link, como citei aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45426/3635 .... **Todavia** se for outro problema poderia me explicar, acho isso muito interessante.

Comment: na verdade se você for desenvolver no android studio, apenas o link no layout html nao será valido, precisa definir isso na activity do app

Comment: O AndroidStudio é apenas uma IDE, mas acho que entendi o que disse irei testar e confirmar, obrigado :D

Comment: sim, porem como estou a fazer aqui, utilizo pasta local webview e pra usar call do html é necessario...rs..mas testa ai e positiva nos...abçs