# Realizar chamadas através de um icone no site pela webwiew do app

Tags: android

Como realizar chamadas telefonicas dentro da webView. no site tem o link da intent do discar do telefone. 
Ex: quando abro o site pelo app de webview que criei ele não chama a função discar do telefone. Alguem que pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione no Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

No código faça:

```
ligar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ligar.getContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"
                    + numerodotelefone)));
        }
    });

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    txtLi.append(tm.getSimOperatorName() + "\n");
    switch (tm.getPhoneType()) {
        case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:
            txtLi.append("GSM \n");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA:
            txtLi.append("CDMA \n");
            break;
    }
```

O elemento txtLi é um textview que pode ficar invisível, no exemplo eu clico em um botão e então chama a ligação passando o número de telefone.

Comment: Aqui tem uma solução com o próprio html https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45425/como-chamar-a-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-ligar-n%C3%BAmero-em-uma-webview?rq=1

Comment: Obrigado Amigo por responder minha pergunta.

Ainda não deu certo mais vou continuar tentando usar o código até conseguir colocar ele no lugar certo. 

hora que conseguir venho marca sua resposta como resolvida e votar em sua reputação. obrigado.